# ng build different app in .angular-cli.json

Tags: angular-cli, angular5

I have this in my `.angular-cli.json`:

```
apps: [
  {...},
  {...}
]
```

when I run `ng build -w`, it seems to only build the first app (element 0/zero in the array). Is there a way to build all the apps with one command? How do I specify which app to build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `--app` flag. You can pass in the index (0 based) of the app you want to build.

For example, this builds the first app in the array:

```
ng build -w --app 0
```

Currently, there isn't a way to build all apps in one command.

Comment: I hear there is a way to do with this app name instead of the index number, but I don't remember the syntax